Is it possible to execute a bat file from JavaScript running in modern browsers?
I have a question – is it possible to run a BAT file with JavaScript in a local HTML document?
My Batch file's purpose is to sleep/hibernate the computer, and looks like this:
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
I want to run it with JavaScript. I know it might be hard because of security reasons, but maybe running an HTA file executing that Batch file?
I tried creating an ActiveX object, but it doesn't work in modern browsers.
Does anyone know the solution?

Modern browsers won't run HTAs either. What you want is not possible.

In pure Javascript no, but in theory you could create a helper stub that runs on each client PC that listens for commands over HTTP.  Similar to how some browser print services work, but this obviously requires each PC with this feature having this stub running.  In other words, it's certainly not a trivial thing to do.

Another option is creating your website inside of an electron app or similar.  But again this is something you will need to install on each machine.

it isn't possible. you can't access anything isn't in browser.
